# Password generator

Tags: dictionary, passwords

I need to generate some passwords (password generator), but I want to avoid characters that can be confused with each other (for example: Chair2bok). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use a character set that you DO want to use rather than those to avoid?

A standard set of 64 characters

```
!#%+23456789:=?@ABCDEFGHJKLMNPRS
TUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

A larger set of 88 characters

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./23456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHJKLMNO
PRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Source: [Characters to avoid in automatically generated passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55556/password-generation-best-practice)

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about how to generate a strong password for SQL Server [HERE](http://blog.digitaltools.com/post/2011/08/19/Generating-Passwords.aspx).
It uses strings that you can remove the characters you don't want. I've already removed some like 1, I, 0, and O.

```
private static string CHARS_LCASE = "abcdefgijkmnopqrstwxyz";
private static string CHARS_UCASE = "ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ";
private static string CHARS_NUMERIC = "23456789";
private static string CHARS_SPECIAL = "*-+_%/";
private static string CHARS_ALL = CHARS_LCASE + CHARS_UCASE 
                                    + CHARS_NUMERIC + CHARS_SPECIAL;
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate passwords of various complexity, you can use the services. For example, [GetPas](http://getpas.ru/) (online password generator).